# ListenableWorker done, but ongoing foreground notification still exists?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am trying to use ListenableWorker to perform some background API calls.

During this process I want to display notification with a progress.

I use **setForegroundAsync()**  function as per this documentation [google docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running)

**The problem is when my ListenableWorker stops, i can still see my ongong notification and i cant remove it.**

This is my refresh fucntion where I change notification parameters:

```
private void updateRefreshStatus(float objectsProcessed, int totalObjects) {
        if (totalObjects == 0) {
            setProgressAsync(new Data.Builder().putFloat(PROGRESS_CONSTANT_ID, 100.0f).build());
            setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(FloatFormatter.roundFloatTwoDigitsAsString(100f)));
        } else {
            setProgressAsync(new Data.Builder().putFloat(PROGRESS_CONSTANT_ID, (objectsProcessed / (float) totalObjects) * 100f).build());
            setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(FloatFormatter.roundFloatTwoDigitsAsString((objectsProcessed / (float) totalObjects) * 100f)));
        }       
    }
```

This is how I create my foregroundInfo:

```
private ForegroundInfo createForegroundInfo(@NonNull String progress) {
        Notification notification = WorkerUtils.prepareProgressNotification("Update",
                "Update progress " + progress + " %",
                getApplicationContext());
        return new ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_PROGRESS_ID,notification);
    }
```

This is my progress notification code:

```
static Notification prepareProgressNotification(String title, String message, Context context) {
        // Make a channel if necessary
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
            // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
            CharSequence name = WorkerConstants.VERBOSE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME;
            String description = WorkerConstants.VERBOSE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION;
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel(WorkerConstants.CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            // Add the channel
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }

        // Create the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, WorkerConstants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVibrate(new long[0]);

        // Show the notification
        return builder.build();
    }
```

I tried calling cancelAll, cancel(id), but it does nothing in my case.

**UPDATE:** Removing .setOngoing(true) from builder, does nothing for me its seems like setForegroundAsync() issue?

Comment: From what I observe, new API says you can cancel worker without registering it via means of PendingIntent which uses same internal token to map shared resources. Your code is quite different and it doesn't show if notification is registered correctly of not. As such notification needs to pass such intent to bind the context. The compact one shouldn't be different. Also your doWork method should close notification on finishing the task by returning success signal at the end.

Comment: Hello.Thanks for reply. I tried to cancel any notification, when my job is done. I was calling something like that:
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
        if(nMgr!=null)
            nMgr.cancelAll();

But it does nothing, with this particular notification that I created using setForegroundAsync, other notifications are successfully destroyed

Comment: What about setting onGoing false and then cancelling notification by Id? I do not see any other reason except the fact that it needs some kind of signal to get off the screen either via intent or by programatically when work is finished. Also please check if you are passing right notification id as build usually generates that id for you in this case.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Yes, see my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60541280/listenableworker-does-not-remove-notification-icon