# ListenableWorker does not remove notification icon

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I am using ListenableWorker to perform background tasks.
Also I want OS to be aware of my service importance, so I call

```
 setForegroundAsync(new ForegroundInfo(WorkerConstants.NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND_ID,
 builder.build()));
```

As suggested in the  google documentation.

But when my service stopped or cancelled, i can still see foreground service notification and i cannot remove it.

Furthermore, I added cancel button to this notification, but it does nothing, I cannot close it:

```
PendingIntent intent = WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                            .createCancelPendingIntent(getId());
                    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_redesign_exit,"Stop",intent);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am having this issue and nothing I do seems to fix it..

Comment: Yes. See my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I filed an issue to google tracker with this. And found out that was totally worng.

Official response as follows:

> Looking at your sample app, you are introducing a race between
>   completion of your ListenableFuture returned by
>   CallbackToFutureAdaptor, and the main looper.
>
> Even without the use of REPLACE one of your Notification updates is
>   posted after your Worker is marked as successful.
>
> However, you can actually avoid the race condition by waiting for the
>   call to setForegroundAsync() to be completed (because that also
>   returns a ListenableFuture). Once you do that - you never have a
>   notification that shows up after your Worker is done.
>
> I will also go ahead and file an improvement on how we can
>   automatically do this even when developers get this wrong.

```
try {
    // This ensures that you waiting for the Notification update to be done.
    setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(0)).get();
} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    // Handle this exception gracefully
    Log.e("FgLW", "Something bad happened", throwable);
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. No matter what I do it still tries to complete after the the result is returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some branch that can end worker immedietaly - add 1 second delay for notification to propagate. `setForeground` claims to be synchronous, but it's clearly not - there's always time notification needs to show. And calling cancel on not shown notification does nothing. It's clearly a race condition, one not handled by google (i'm not even sure if that can be handled by app).

Extended explanation:

I have code that in single scenario can return immediately. Worker looks like that:

```
setForeground(getForegroundInfo())
loggingRepository.uploadLogs()
```

That's it, could not be simpler. BUT, logging repository have this check on start:

```
if (!userIdentity.isLoggedIn) return
```

So if user is not loggedIn - do nothing. And if this scenario happend - notification just stayed on. The only thing i had to do is to add delay like that (it's a CoroutineWorker)

```
setForeground(getForegroundInfo())
loggingRepository.uploadLogs()
delay(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a ktx suspending function called `setForeground()` on the latest version of the Work Manager library which does an `.await()` on the listener and turns it synchronous, if you use Coroutines.

Comment: It doesn't actually work. I'm doing that and am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

**[Official Doc as follows:](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running)**

> ListenableWorker now supports the setForegroundAsync() API, and
> CoroutineWorker supports a suspending setForeground() APi

So the Solution to the above problem is that you must perform the busy job before returning Result.success(). Otherwise this exception will be thrown

> Calls to setForegroundAsync() must complete before a ListenableWorker
> signals completion of work by returning an instance of Result.

**Check my code snippet for your Solution:**

```
    public static void startCloudWorker() {
    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CloudWorker.class)
                    .setInitialDelay(..., TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    ...
                    .build();

    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
}


public class CloudWorker extends Worker {
    public CloudWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        final ForegroundInfo foregroundInfo = createForegroundInfo(...)

        setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo);
        
        // Some busy job here...

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Better forget the `setForegroundAsync` and go for the traditional way as explained here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Here is what I used:

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String title = context.getString(R.string.str_synchronisation);
    String cancel = context.getString(R.string.str_cancel_synchronisation);
    // This PendingIntent can be used to cancel the worker
    PendingIntent intent = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .createCancelPendingIntent(getId());
    //notificationManager.cancel(notification_ID);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notif_ch_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sync_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText("Use this Content")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
//                // Add the cancel action to the notification which can
//                // be used to cancel the worker
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, cancel, intent);
    notificationManager.notify(notification_ID, builder.build());
```

don't forget to keep an instance of the notification manager:

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Update your notification with:

```
builder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.str_veuiller_patienter)
                + ", fichier " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + totalfiles);
notificationManager.notify(notification_ID, builder.build());
```

cancel your notification with:

```
notificationManager.cancel(notification_ID);
```

Comment: While useful in some situations, this answer does not solve the original issue. Using `setForegroundAsync` is mandatory when letting a WorkManager worker start a foreground service for long running tasks. Managing your own notification gets rid of the notification, but you still cannot use the foreground service feature properly. It seems like a bug in the WorkManager library...